# Uniform has no logp method

Tags: pymc3

I must be missing something here. I can calculate the log probability from a Normal distribution, but not a Uniform distribution:

```
>>> import pymc as pm
>>> with pm.Model():
...     b = pm.Normal('b', 0, 1)
...
>>> b.logp({'b': 2)
array(-2.9189385332046727)

>>> with pm.Model():
...     a = pm.Uniform('a', 0, 1)
...
>>> a.logp({'a': 0.5})
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'TransformedRV' object has no attribute 'logp'
```

Answer (score 2):

PyMC3 transform bounded distributions, like the uniform, to unbounded ones. So you could ask PyMC3 to do not transform the variable:

```py
with pm.Model() as model:
    a = pm.Uniform('a', 0, 1, transform=None)
a.logp({'a': 0.5})
```

or ask for the transformed variable like:

```py
with pm.Model() as model:
    a = pm.Uniform('a', 0, 1)
model.logp({'a_interval__': 0.5})
```

You may want to check the `unobserved_RVs` and `free_RVs` attributes of `model`

Comment: Thanks, do you know what are the downsides of not transforming the variables?

Comment: Variables are automatically transformed to make inference methods work more efficiently, thus not transforming variables is not a good idea unless you really know what you are doing.